# Add array to hash in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I try to add array in hash.

```
if ( not exists $hashtime{ $arr[0] }{ $date }{ $hour }{ $min } ) {
    print "$min not exist";
    $hashtime{ $arr[0] }{ $date }{ $hour }{ $min } = [ $sec ];
    $create++;
};
```

And received the error:

> Not a HASH reference at ./sort_log_by_ip.pl line 63,  line 1.

Why is this code wrong?

In [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS) I see this construction, and I'm using something similar:

```
while ( <> ) {
     next unless s/^(.*?):\s*//;
     $HoA{$1} = [ split ];
}
```

#### Update

Code before:

```
if ( not exists $hashtime{ $arr[0] } ) {
    $hashtime{ $arr[0] } = ( $date => { $hour => { $min => [ $sec ] } } );
    $create++; 
    print "create for IP: $arr[0]\n";
}

if ( not exists $hashtime{ $arr[0] }{$date} ) {
    $hashtime{ $arr[0] }{ $date } = ( $hour => { $min => [ $sec ] } );
    $create++;
    print "create for IP: $arr[0] DATE: $date\n";
}

if ( not exists $hashtime{ $arr[0] }{$date}{$hour} ) {
    $hashtime{ $arr[0] }{ $date }{ $hour } = ( $min => [$sec] );
    $create++;
    print "create for IP: $arr[0] DATE: $date HOUR: $hour\n";
}
```

Comment: Show the complete code. Your code errors at line 63, but there's no way to know what line 63 is in your code-snippet or what any of the other variables are or do...

Comment: if (not exists $hashtime{$arr[0]}{$date}{$hour}{$min}){ - this is line 63.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a list `( )` instead of a hash reference `{ }`, in all `if` blocks.

When you say

```
$hashtime{$arr[0]} = ( $date => { $hour => { $min => [$sec] } } );
```

because of LIST `( )` being evaluated in scalar context what happens is equivalent to

```
$hashtime{$arr[0]} = ( $date, { $hour => { $min => [$sec] } } );
```

ending up as

```
$hashtime{$arr[0]} = { $hour => { $min => [$sec] } };
```

since the `,` operator evaluates and discards operands one at a time, returning the last one.

The next `if` goes similarly and you then have either of (or both)

```
$hashtime{$arr[0]}{$date}{$min}{[$sec]}
$hashtime{$arr[0]}{$hour}{$min}{[$sec]}
```

However, the code that draws the error

```
if (not exists $hashtime{$arr[0]}{$date}{$hour})
```

needs a hashref at both `$arr[0]` and `{$date}`, while it clearly doesn't have both.

---

In both `if` blocks you need to assign a hash reference, obtained using `{ }`

```
$hashtime{$arr[0]} = { $date => { $hour => { $min => [$sec] } } };
```

and

```
$hashtime{$arr[0]}{$date} = { $hour => { $min => [$sec] } };
```

as well as in the last `if` block.

---

Please indent your code properly.  It is very hard to work with it the way it was posted.

Comment: Thanks for help!
$hashtime{$arr[0]} = ( $date, { $hour=>{$min=>[$sec]} } ); - error is here. You are write/
I have not written for perl more then 10 year.

Comment: @Skif  That appears to be the only error; and you got that same thing right everywhere else.